# Non-maximised window on second screen disappears when moving mouse to second screen

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, focus, window-focus

This one's a bit hard to explain, and I haven't found a good way to google it. Pretty much if I have a non-maximised window (say, notepad) open on my right (secondary) screen, sometimes when I move my cursor from my left (primary) screen to the right screen, the window on the right screen will just vanish. IIRC it's not being minimised, just ending up behind all the maximised windows (so the Z-order is just changing).

I'm on Windows 10, so I previously assumed it was probably was a Win10 bug, however a colleague just called me over to her computer to check out a problem she was having and it turned out to be exactly the same issue I am seeing. She's on Windows 7 so it's not a Win10 bug. I then wondered if perhaps Teamviewer was causing the issue but after quitting it she was still able to replicate.

My colleague is able to replicate reliably. She has Chrome on her left screen and a work program opened on her right screen. She types for a few seconds in Chrome on the left screen, then moves her cursor to the right screen to copy some information and at that exactly moment the work software vanishes.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any consistency, and I also can't find a way to replicate reliably. I'm at a loss as to what I could try next to narrow down this problem. Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a known way to fix it?

Comment: What is the work software? If it is a custom application, have the developers been informed?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it also happens to me with notepad. It's not specific to that software. But yes, it's custom.